# Docker - Identify Unused Volumes

Tags: docker, volumes, portainer, mounted-volumes

I'm trying to find a way to identify **what container created a volume** as well as **where it wants to mount to** & also **If it will be reused when the container restarts** for volumes that are currently not in use.

I know I can see what container is ***currently*** using a volume, & where it's mounted to in said container, but that isn't enough. I need to identify containers that are no longer running.

### The Situation

I've noticed a frequently reoccurring problem with Docker, I create a container to test it out, make some adjustments, restart it, make some more, restart it, until I get it working how I want it to.

In the process, many times, I come across containers that create worthless volumes. These, after the fact, I can identify as 8K volumes not currently in use & just delete them.

But many times these volumes aren't even persistent, as the container will create a new one each time it runs.

At times I look at my `Volumes` list & see over 100 volumes, none of which are currently in use. The 8KB ones I'll delete without a second thought, but the ones that are 12KB or 24KB or 100KB or 5Mb, etc, etc I don't want to just delete.

I use a Portainer agent inside Portainer solely for the ability to quickly browse these volumes & decide if it needs to be kept, transferred to a Bind mount, or just discarded, but it's becoming more & more of a problem & I figure there has to be some way to identify the container they came from. I'm sure it will require some sort of code exploration, but where? is there not a tool to do this? If I know where the information is I should be able to write a script or even make a container just for this purpose, I just don't know where to begin.

The most annoying thing is when a container creates a second container & that container, that I have no control over, is using a volume, but it creates a new one each time it starts.

Some examples

- `adoring_hellman` created by VS Code Server container `linuxserver/code-server`
- `datadog/agent` creates a container I believe is called `st-vector` or something similar
- - Both which have access to `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: This all seems like it heavily depends on the images in use and how they're built.  Absent details like the images' Dockerfiles or the corresponding `docker run` commands it's hard to tell.  If an image has a Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive it could cause a volume leak like what you're seeing; if you're giving a container unrestricted access to the host via the Docker socket then all bets are off and that container could be doing literally anything, including randomly creating volumes because it feels like it.

Comment: Any container can create a volume if the `Dockerfile` calls for a volume & it isn't overwritten by a Bind/Volume mount in the DockerRun/Compose. It's understandable because sometimes persistent data is necessary & needed. The problem, however, is when it calls for a volume but makes a new one each start. That serves no purpose, but happens on multiple containers on multiple machines, so it isn't a glitch. Once I know where they are being called from I can create a bind mount to override them, I just need to be able to tell where it's calling & what's calling for it